# How do I replace colorbox with the fancybox in OpenCart?

Tags: fancybox, opencart

I have managed to get the fancybox to work on the product and category pages but it is not working with the shopping cart and checkout.  I am not sure which files I should be changing so they will work with the fancybox.  Thank you for anyone that may be able to help me here.
Fancybox Version: 2.1.5
Opencart: 1.5.5.1

Comment: Welcome to **StackOverflow**! What is the reason for using fancybox (or replacing colorbox that is already in OC from v. 1.5.3)? If You think You need fancybox for sure and cannot use the colorbox, then download also the older version (1.5.0.x to 1.5.2.x) and check how fancybox is used there. The usage of both the plugins is very similar therefore linking fancybox sources and then replacing the `.colorbox()` with `.fancybox()` and using the right properties should be enough at all relevant places...

Comment: Thank you shadyyx for your reply, I think I will try the colorbox, it was just that I was familiar with fancybox.  Can you tell me whether colorbox will play swf files?

Comment: Hi shadyyx, I have decided to persevere with the fancybox and give it another go.  It works great within the product page or category page but for some reason all the drop down questions in Checkout won't work or the top right hand - Shopping Cart 1 item(s) NZ$15.00 won't drop down either.  I changed the swapped the colorbox code in template/checkout/cart.tpl, payment_method.tpl, register-new.tpl and register.tpl.  The code I changed it with is:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
     maxWidth : 800,
     maxHeight : 600,
     fitToView : false,
     width  : '70%',
     height  : '70%',
     autoSize : false,
     closeClick : false,
     openEffect : 'none',
     closeEffect : 'none'
    });
   });
   </script>

Answer (score 1):

Use this extension

The below mentioned extension give you fancybox zoom option

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=5389

Comment: Thank you for the extension link Siva, I still have not been able to get the fancybox working in opencart so I will have to work on it before I can add this great tool.

Comment: in checkout page why you required the fancybox?

Comment: On the link Shopping Cart
0 item(s) - NZ$0.00 the dropdown arrow would not work when i had the fancybox working on the products and category pages.  It also would not open the shopping cart link, so I assume the fancybox needs to be activated on these pages?